# É possível deletar um arquivo se não existir referencia dele no banco usando mySQL

Tags: mysql, linux, diretório

Gostaria de saber se alguém conhece alguma forma de criar um "gatilho" no MySQL que ao excluir um valor da tabela, exclua junto um arquivo no servidor, por exemplo:

1. Exclui o item da `tbl_imagens` cujo nome seja `imagem_1001.jpg`;
2. O gatilho pega o valor `imagem_1001.jpg` e exclui no diretório `uploads/imagem_1001.jpg`

Obs:

- Não me interessa salvar imagens no banco de dados;
- Não me interessa excluir com PHP `unlink()`;

Comment: Voce precisa mesmo excluir um arquivo através do MySQL? Não pode utilizar a linguagem de programação?

Comment: Não vejo muita lógica em fazer isto pelo banco, nem sei se existe a possibilidade. Como você esta trabalhando com uma linguagem de programação faça esta exclusão com ela, será mais coerente.

Comment: Sim, e pesquisando, vi gente comentando que consegue inserir comandos de linux no gatilho. RM por exemplo;

Comment: Sim, tem muita lógica nisso, você estará evitando muitas condições e consultas em um determinado sistema que faça uso de uma complexa cadeia de imagens

Comment: Uma alternativa seria criar uma tabela de `imagens_para_excluir`. Essa tabela poderia ser executada a partir de um sheel script que consulta essa tabela, remove os arquivos do disco e trunca essa tabela. Você poderia agendar a execução desse script via cronjob.

Comment: Concordo com o comentário do @gmsantos. Separação de conceitos: Banco é para armazenar dados, FileSystem para gerenciar arquivos. Alguma outra camada da solução deve fazer o purge de arquivos.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema?